# How to use array.filter + map on an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, array.prototype.map

I'm trying to filter this array to get the id and convert from a string to a number. I want to use filter and map? Wanting to know how to make it as clear as possible.

```
var pets = [
  { id: '1', name: 'rupert', readyForHome: 'No', age: 12, personality: ['friendly', 'lazy', 'loving']},
  { id: '2', name: 'mrs fluffy', readyForHome: 'Yes', age: 2, personality: ['affectionate', 'playful', 'shy']},
  { id: '3', name: 'tabitha', readyForHome: 'Yes', age: 4, personality: ['aggressive', 'independent']},
  { id: '4', name: 'lily', readyForHome: 'No', age: 8, personality: ['friendly', 'playful', 'mischievous']},
];
```

Comment: please add the search parameters, the output and what you have tried. you may have a look here, too: [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is `map` to get down to an array of ids as numbers:

```
pets = pets.map(function(pet) {
  return Number(pet.id);
});
```

```js
var pets=[{id:"1",name:"rupert",readyForHome:"No",age:12,personality:["friendly","lazy","loving"]},{id:"2",name:"mrs fluffy",readyForHome:"Yes",age:2,personality:["affectionate","playful","shy"]},{id:"3",name:"tabitha",readyForHome:"Yes",age:4,personality:["aggressive","independent"]},{id:"4",name:"lily",readyForHome:"No",age:8,personality:["friendly","playful","mischievous"]}];

pets = pets.map(function(pet) {
  return Number(pet.id);
});

console.log(pets);
```

Comment: thanks for the help, but mine is returning "object" 11 times. here is my code

Comment: function petSorter (pet) {
 cats = cats.map(function(pet) {
  return Number(pet.id);
});

}

console.log(cats);

Comment: @JacobJabocJones, it might be helpful to see a more full example of your code, you can use [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) if that would help.

Comment: never used JSFiddle before. how do i use it to show you it?

Comment: Ah, ok. I didn't know that was the full code. Anyways, JSFiddle allows you to put in your JS, CSS, and HTML, and then click the save in the top left, once you do that, you can copy-paste the url and provide it to wherever you want.

Comment: @JacobJabocJones, you're close, you just need to call the function, return and value from it. What you were seeing when you did a console.log was the actual cats variable from when you created it (array of objects). Check this updated example https://jsfiddle.net/9k9sb189/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
var petIds = pets.map(function (pet) {
    petId = parseInt(pet.id);
    return petId;
});
```